# Photon how would I hide a start game button from the client but keep it for the host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

So this goes into how I would hide a start game button for the client but keep it for the host. I am new and don't really know where to start on this so any help would be perfect. But my thoughts on how to do this is to set the button Active if you are the host but if you are the client do not set it to active. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In Photon there is no "Host" .. only a "Master Client" => You can check [`PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a57f4f9f3db3f4e69d7262affd7b673ee) and do e.g.

```
yourButton.gameObject.SetActive(photonNetwork.IsMasterClient);
```